# Filter out data from Ansible Output

Tags: json, list, ansible

I need to get hostnames extracted from an output I get from running a playbook as given below.

```
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    changed: false
    clusters:
      RDG1-DC-2:
        datacenter: RDG1
        drs_default_vm_behavior: fullyAutomated
        drs_enable_vm_behavior_overrides: true
        drs_vmotion_rate: 3
        enable_ha: false
        enabled_drs: true
        enabled_vsan: false
        ha_admission_control_enabled: true
        ha_failover_level: 1
        ha_host_monitoring: enabled
        ha_restart_priority:
        - medium
        ha_vm_failure_interval:
        - 30
        ha_vm_max_failure_window:
        - -1
        ha_vm_max_failures:
        - 3
        ha_vm_min_up_time:
        - 120
        ha_vm_monitoring: vmMonitoringDisabled
        ha_vm_tools_monitoring:
        - vmMonitoringDisabled
        hosts:
        - folder: /RDG1/host/RDG1-DC-2
          name: esxi7-host3.hmlab.local
        - folder: /RDG1/host/RDG1-DC-2
          name: esxi7-host4.hmlab.local
        moid: domain-c1009
        resource_summary:
          cpuCapacityMHz: 27264
          cpuUsedMHz: 494
          memCapacityMB: 14326
          memUsedMB: 6493
          pMemAvailableMB: 0
          pMemCapacityMB: 0
          storageCapacityMB: 50944
          storageUsedMB: 37489
        tags: []
        vsan_auto_claim_storage: false
    failed: false
```

All I need from this output is to extract the name from hosts: `item`

It should give me:

- `esxi7-host3.hmlab.local`
- `esxi7-host4.hmlab.local`

I did try using the following but it spits it out as a dict but not as a list on which I can loop

```
- set_fact:
  host_clusters: "{{ item.value.hosts | json_query('[*].name') | to_nice_yaml }}"
with_dict: "{{ cluster_info.clusters }}"
loop_control:
  label: '{{ item.key }}'
- debug:
      msg: "{{ host_clusters }}"
```

Comment: This should work. What output/error are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

Easier and without the usage of a loop, neither of a JMESPath query, use the [`values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20values#dict.values) method of Python dictionary along with the [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map).

```yaml
- debug:
    var: (cluster_info.clusters.values() | first).hosts | map(attribute='name')
```

---

And if you do have multiple clusters:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: cluster_info.clusters.values() | map(attribute='hosts') | flatten | map(attribute='name')
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: (cluster_info.clusters.values() | first).hosts | map(attribute='name')
      vars:
        cluster_info:
          clusters:
            RDG1-DC-2:
              hosts:
              - folder: /RDG1/host/RDG1-DC-2
                name: esxi7-host3.hmlab.local
              - folder: /RDG1/host/RDG1-DC-2
                name: esxi7-host4.hmlab.local
```

This yields:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  (cluster_info.clusters.values() | first).hosts | map(attribute='name'):
  - esxi7-host3.hmlab.local
  - esxi7-host4.hmlab.local
```

Comment: Many Thanks mate. I was able to figure out by using the following - host_clusters: "{{ item.value.hosts | map(attribute='name') | list }}"